# Cypress does not support multi window and multiple tabs so how we can handle both

Tags: cypress

I am trying to automate a website using cypress and I came across a problem where in I have to handle below tag. On click, new window gets opened which gets displayed out of the test runner.

> a href="javascript:ContextTradeMenuPopup('View/Edit Trade')">View/Edit
>   Trade /a

I understand Cypress does not support multi window but as a workaround I can get the href tag and copy the URL and can open the URL in same runner, but in the above example there is no URL.

Can anyone help with different ways available in Cypress to handle multi window/ multiple tab behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The work around you mentioned is currently the only work around that is available. So you should retrieve the URL of the new window/tab and visit that directly. If you can't do that you sadly can't automate it.